# Push New Items Onto Array in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, fetch-api

I have a Vuex store in a NuxtJS app that has a single item in state: `newsArticles`.  It is an array -- and my goal is to use the fetch api to add new items to that array on a regular basis.  That is, every time I make a fetch api, I want to add the results of that call to the array.

The problem is, every time I make a new call, the old items are erased and replaced by the new results.

Here is my code:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      newsArticles: []
    },
    getters: {
      getNewsArticles: (state) => state.newsArticles
    },
    mutations: {
      setNewsArticles(state, jsonItems) {
        state.newsArticles.push(...jsonItems)
      }
    },
    actions: {
      async fetchNewsArticles({ commit }, apiUrl) {

        const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
        const json = await response.json()

        commit('setNewsArticles', json.items)
      }
    }
  })
}

export default createStore
```

As far as I can tell, the `setNewsArticles` mutation should add new items to the array -- that is what the push method does.  And yet, that is not what happens.  Instead, the only results that show up in the array are the latest results of the fetch api call.

Any idea what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

This is how I am using the store in the `index.vue` file in the `Pages`directory:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="article in articles" :key="article.id">
    <div><b>Title: </b> {{ article.title }}</div>
  </li>
</ul>

...

  async fetch({ store }) {
    await store.dispatch(
      'fetchNewsArticles',
      `[UNIQUE_URL]`
    )
  },
  computed: {
    articles() {
      return this.$store.getters.getNewsArticles
    }
  }
```

Comment: How are you registering the store with your Vue instance?

Comment: I must admit -- this is the first time I have used Vuex - so I'm not sure how to answer your question.  All I can say is that this is a NuxtJS app -- and I believe that Vuex takes care of registering Vuex.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: If you add `console.log` inside mutatation, `console.log(state.newsArticles);
state.newsArticles.push(...jsonItems)`, what does it log?